# Sanitizers in Python native module

Tags: python, python-3.x, gcc, address-sanitizer

I would like to use GCC's sanitizers for a native module.

I use the link options:

```
-static-libasan -static-libtsan -static-liblsan -static-libubsan -fsanitize=address -lasan -lubsan
```

When I load the native module it prints the error message:

```
ASan runtime does not come first in initial library list; you should either link runtime to your application or manually preload it with LD_PRELOAD.
```

Now this seems like the static flags not working.
Is it possible to use sanitizers for a shared object only or is it necessary to have sanitizers linked into python3 directly?

Comment: Also see [27. Dynamic Analysis with Clang](https://docs.python.org/devguide/clang.html) in the Developer Manual. It was written back when only Clang provided sanitizers.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is probably caused by `-static-libasan` flag which tells compiler that `libasan.a` will be linked by main executable and so there is no need to link it to plugin. See [wiki](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/AddressSanitizerAsDso) if you are interested in gory details. In general, to sanitize just a single module of large app you should compile and link it with `-fsanitize=address` and then run application with `LD_PRELOAD`ed libasan.so (`LD_PRELOAD` is needed to ensure that libasan is able to intercept all necessary bits of glibc).

Note sanitizing a single module may miss memory errors which happen in main executable even if they are caused by bad API calls from your module. To detect these, you'll need to sanitize executable as well.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason linking in `-lasan` didn't work either. However, `LD_PRELOAD` worked fine.

Try `LD_PRELOAD`, if that is feasible for you.